# Basic Bayesian Linear Regression prediction with PyMC3

Tags: linear-regression, pymc3

I would like to use my PyMC3 LR model to get an 80% HPD range for the value of the predicted variable `y` as new data becomes available.
Thus, extrapolate a credible distribution of values for `y` for a new value of `x` not in my original dataset.

Model:

```
with pm.Model() as model_tlr:
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=10)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=10)
    epsilon = pm.Uniform('epsilon', 0, 25)

    nu = pm.Deterministic('nu', pm.Exponential('nu_', 1/29) + 1)
    mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', alpha + beta * x)

    yl = pm.StudentT('yl', mu=mu, sd=epsilon, nu=nu, observed=y)

    trace_tlr = pm.sample(50000, njobs=3)
```

After burnin I sample from the posterior and get an HPD

```
ppc_tlr = pm.sample_ppc(btrace_tlr, samples=10000, model=model_tlr)
ys = ppc_tlr['yl']
y_hpd = pm.stats.hpd(ys, alpha=0.2)
```

Which is great for visualizing the HPD around the central tendency (using fill_between)
[image]

But I would like to now use the model to get an HPD for `y` when `x=126.2` (for example) and the initial dataset didn't contain an observed `x=126.2`

The way I understand sampling from the posterior is that there are 10k samples for each of the available `x` values in the dataset and hence there isn't a corresponding sampling in `ys` for `x=126.2` as it wasn't observed.

Basically, is there a way to use my model to obtain a distribution of credible  values (based on the model) from a predictor value `x=126.2` which only became available after the model was built?
If so, how?

Thank you

EDIT:
Found [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249122/generating-predictions-from-inferred-parameters-in-pymc3?rq=1) which mentions

> Function under development (will likely eventually get added to pymc3) that will allow to predict posteriors for new data.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so it's possible, more or less as described in the above SO post.
However, there has since been a sample_ppc function added to PyMC3 which makes the author's run_ppc redundant.

First, setup a Theano shared variable for x.

```
from theano import shared
x_shared = shared(x)
```

Then use x_shared when building the model.

After the model is built, add the new datum and update the shared variable

```
x_updated = np.append(x, 126.2)
x_shared.set_value(x_updated)
```

Re-run the PPC sample generator with the original trace and model objects

```
new_ppc = pm.sample_ppc(btrace_tlr, samples=10000, model=model_tlr)
```

The sampling of the posterior for the new datum is found with

```
sample = new_ppc['yl'][:,-1]
```

I can then get the HPD with

```
pm.stats.hpd(sample)
```

> array([ 124.56126638,  128.63795388])

Sklearn has spoiled me into thinking there should be a simple `predict` interface...